# Python Regex: How Can I find Recurring Blocks of Texts in a Text File

Tags: python, regex, text, nlp

I'm trying to parse repeating blocks of text that all begin with '----BEGIN---' and end with '---END', using Python. So the text file will look like below. Basically, I want to be able to find each block (words, numbers, and special characters) and parse them for further analysis. The code below is as close as I have gotten, but it returns the entire document, not each block. Any help would be appreciated.

```
block_search = re.compile('----BEGIN---.*---END',re.DOTALL)
with open(file,'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()
    result = re.findall(block_search,text)
```

----BEGIN---
Words Special Character Numbers words Special character words numbers words words.
words numbers words Special character words numbers words words
words numbers words words
---END

----BEGIN---
Words words numbers words Special character words numbers words words.
words numbers words Special character words numbers words words
words numbers words words ...
---END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'----BEGIN---.*---END'` will match anything from the first occurence of `----BEGIN---` to the last occurence of `---END`, that is what `.*` does.
If you want to find the specific block, use `.*?`, it will stop after the first occurrence of substring after it, or in other  words,  it will search only until it finds the substring after it.

```py
block_search = re.compile('----BEGIN---.*?---END',re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: That got me 90% of the way there. What I don't understand now is that with re.findall() it does not find every instance of the block.

Comment: Yeah, you were missing `?` only. For the sample data you have, it is finding both the occurrences.

Comment: No. I understood you there. There was a different problem with my code that prevented it from finding the following iterations of the blocks. Thanks for the help!